# Store wordpress media completely off my server and on a CDN

Tags: cdn, cloud

This question has been asked before, and it is pretty dead with no one answering the question properly so I am asking it again.

Is there a CDN service that can be configured with a plugin or manually that simply allows you to host your uploaded media files completely off your server, but allow you to manage the attachments like normal.

These are key simple points...

1. Uploaded files are sorted into folders (just like normal)
2. Attachments can be deleted - which in turn removes the attachment files off the CDN
3. Files only to be uploaded directly to CDN (not mirrored)
4. The ability to move previous uploads to the CDN and relink them
5. Multisite compatibility

I've got budget, but it's just finding such a service that does all the above.

I have a server with alot of wordpress installations on, and 4 of them are extremely heavy with photographic content, so I just want to go the down the CDN route and have all media stored/uploaded that way.

I've tried all these plugins, and none of these do what I need...

1. [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) - Only tried with Amazon Cloudfront - no option to direct upload
2. [WP2Cloud](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp2cloud-wordpress-to-cloud/) - MySQL incompatible
3. [WP Read-Only](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wpro/) - Almost perfect but unable to delete files - and no multisite compatibly.

I've tried more but they just mirror or copy using cron, which is useless for me because the whole point I would of thought is to get the media strain off your server and live safely in the cloud (which is backed up anyway).

Surely something must exist that can do everything I need.

Thanks in advance

[http://wpquestions.com/](http://wpquestions.com/question/showChronoLoggedIn/id/8456)

Comment: "...point I would of thought is to get the media strain off your server..."-- Images sitting on your server are virtually no strain on the server. The strain comes from _serving_ the files from your server. When you tested these plugins did you check (HttpFox?, WireShark?) to see where the files are actually coming from when you load the site?

Comment: [@s_ha_dum](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/21376/s-ha-dum) Sorry what I mean by strain on my server is, that my server is only 1 terabyte, and it's nearly reached full capacity so I need to move everything off onto an CDN with unlimited space where I pay them to serve. The plugins above work but none of them do all of my 5 points.

Comment: Your requirements are mutually exclusive. You can not manage remotely hosted attachments like normal, because considerable chunk of that is about manipulating local files. While you can slice what you need in practice and what you don't, this really seems like a custom development job.

Comment: @Rarst thank you for this, I've just come to that realisation yesterday - though I thought this would be an obvious problem for a lot of people, space running out on their server. But like you say - either buy another server or a use a custom development.